# Is this Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: logarithms, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f$ be defined by $f(x)=x\log(1+\frac{a}{x})$, where $a$ is a positive scalar.

Is $f$  Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: what is the domain ?  $(0, \infty)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain is
$$D=(-\infty,-a)\cup (0,+\infty) $$

$f $ is differentiable at $D $ and
$$f'(x)=\ln (1+a/x)-\frac {a}{x+a}$$

$f'$ is unbounded at $D $ thus it is not Lipschitz at $D $.

Answer (score 0):

If $(-\infty, -a)$  is included in domain , then clearly $f$ is not Lipchitz since 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow - a^-} f(x) = - \infty$$

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima It is 0,

Comment: I know .........

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima 
تصبح على خير


from USA